# dynamic bootstrap form alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a dynamic form that i want to align like this.

[image]

i tried using bootstrap grid system but im still not getting it.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Time Schedule:</label>
                <div id="items">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-2"><h5>TO</h5></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add-entry").click(function(e){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#items").append('<div class="col-sm-3">'
            +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker></div>'
            +'<div class="col-sm-2"><h5>TO</h5></div><div class="col-sm-3">'
            +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="12:00" data-timepicker></div>'
            +'<div class="col-sm-4"><input type="button" value="delete-entry" class="delete-entry"></div>');
    });

    $('body').on('click','.delete-entry',function(e){

        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });


});
```

Comment: Hi you need to post all of your code (like `#add-entry` doesn't exist, so you aren't providing the form elements for your design). It's best if you provide a working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a fiddle for your requirements. You were not actually completing `col-md-12` grid as you said. I've created the same UI using `col-xs-12` grid. Also, When you clicked on `Delete entry` you were actually removing the `div` of button itself.
Here is the working fiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjnb0gg6/)

Comment: perfect answer! but its still not working in my device, i think im lacking a script tag but im not sure what.

Comment: Is it same as the fiddle I created? or different? Can you post your code?

Comment: It should have worked. Have you copied the whole code or the changes? I suggest you to take a close look on both the codes and look if there are any changes.

Comment: i already copied everything, your code is perfect. i find it odd that it doesnt work here, thankyou anyway..

Comment: When you run your code, open the developer tools in the browser using `F12` and see if there are any errors. It will help you to narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it already, i added

```
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
```

below the last input field in the html file to complete the "col-md-12" grid, i adjusted the javascript col-md's to match the ones in the html.

however i have another problem, it seems that my delete button is not working anymore